# How to calculate response time (ping) from iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, url

I want to check whether servers are active or not from the iphone application programmatically.

How do I calculate the time for getting response from the server?

I have heard about ping, what to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to connect to your server (using for example Reachability by Apple http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) and use an `NSTimer` to time the response. But that won't be as precise as a `ping` command

Comment: hi., thank you so much for your help. can you please tell me how do i calculate time taken to get response from the server?

Comment: like I said, NSTimer ;) look for the documentation, but basically us the fire message before calling Reachability, and calculate the time using the timeInterval property after getting Reachability response

Comment: Thank you, i will do as u said.

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to accept answers (click the checkmarck bellow the down arrow on the left of an answer)

Answer (score -2):

When you want to get any response from server , first check if any network connection available or not by implementing Reachability as told by Thomas.

Now if you have active network connection then you can request the server and catch the response as described below.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse;
        httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
        NSString *serverResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", statusCode];
        NSLog ( @ "status code =% d" , statusCode);
        if(statusCode!=200){
            UIAlertView * Alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle : @"Problem"
                                                               Message : serverResponse
                                                              delegate : nil 
                                                     cancelButtonTitle : @ " OK "
                                                     otherButtonTitles : nil ];
            [Alert Show ];
            [Alert Release ];

        }
}
```

You can refer this for [List of HTTP Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)